# DatePicker selects date before minDate

Tags: android, datepicker

Updates:

```
DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getContext(), new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            // do some stuff
        }
    }, year, month, day);

DatePicker datePicker = datePickerDialog.getDatePicker();
datePicker.updateDate(2018, 2, 7);
datePicker.setMinDate(1272920400000L); //milliseconds since epoch for 2010.04.10
datePickerDialog.show();
```

The problem happens inside any DatePicker object, it's not because of my code. You just go inside a DatePickerDialog and try to replicate.

---

I have a DatePicker and I've set minDate to be 4th of May 2010.

But when you select, for example, 1st May 2011, and then click left arrow until you reach May 2010, it will be automatically selecte 1st May 2010, which is unavailable. Then, OK button will work.

What do you think about this? Is there a way to solve it? I've searched all the Internet and didn't find anything. Thank you!

[image]

Comment: `I've set minDate` how have you done that?

Comment: include your code in the question

Comment: @azizbekian I added in the code. It's a method that you can call and set a minimum date for a DatePicker.

Comment: @Zacktamondo I updated my answer. It's not only my case. It's an issue in the DatePickerDialog.